# How do I write this simple threshold algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

```
score = 50;
thresholdMax = 70;
thresholdMin = 30;

if (score > thresholdMax) return 1;
if (score < thresholdMin) return 0;
else return //the fraction between thresholdMax and thresholdMin that score is, as a value between 0 and 1.
```

I know this has to be so easy, but I just can't seem to think of how to write it.

I tried it like this but I don't think it's working:

```
spread = ThresholdMax - ThresholdMin;
diff = score - ThresholdMin;
return Math.round(diff / spread);
```

Comment: Can you add an example. Example, score = 40, 50, 60: what do you want?

Comment: What do you mean by 'I don't think it's working'? Implement it and test it. Looks good to me.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Maybe I was mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble with something like:

```
spread = maxThreshold - minThreshold;
diff = score - minThreshold;
return Math.round(diff / spread);
```

when `score` is between the two thresholds, is that `diff / spread` is going to be a number between zero and one, meaning that rounding it will always only ever give you zero *or* one, rather than the fractional value that you seem to desire.

If it's *within* the minimum and maximum  (as your question indicates), just use:

```
fraction = (score - thresholdMin) / (thresholdMax- thresholdMin);
```

Sample fractions for that would be:

```
score  fraction
-----  --------
   31     0.025
   35     0.125
   40     0.250
   45     0.375
   50     0.500
   69     0.975
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also try using the `min` and `max` functions:

```
return min(1, max(0, (score-thresholdMin)/(thresholdMax-thresholdMin)));
```

Comment: Francis, you can get code *blocks* by indenting four spaces without using backticks. Have modified to show how.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest else statement should be like:

```
if (score > thresholdMax) return 1;
if (score < thresholdMin) return 0;
else{
  return (score-thresholdMin)/(thresholdMax-thresholdMin);
}
```